The ability to engage in an unhealthy behavior (e.g. smoking) late in life may indicate strong overall health. Is there a name for this "bias"?
Is there a name for this phenomenon in epidemiology?  I'd like to read about examples and approaches to identify and account for it.
The scenario:
Imagine you have an elderly cohort.
Most of these individuals were dedicated cigarette smokers at some point in their lives.  Indeed, among those who are former smokers most quit smoking only because they became so unhealthy to continue.  Emphysema makes smoking physically impossible, for example.
On the other hand, those who continue to smoke into old age do so because they are otherwise healthy enough to continue.  No emphysema.
In this cohort smoking is an indicator of good overall health.  If used as a predictor of short-term mortality smoking will be seen as "protective" in whatever model you use.

A version of survivor bias, maybe? Search this site for examples of use

Sounds like survivorship bias. When we mistake the surviving subpopulation as the total population.

This sounds like selection into treatment based on the potential treated outcome, a violation of the conditional independence assumption.

Correlation does not imply causality - here smoking is correlated with good health, but not a cause of it.
Note also, that good health is a misnomer here, based on using extreme condition (emphysema) - most people give up smoking for more benign reasons, and absence of emphysema does not mean absence of smoking-related health problems (cardiac, predisposition to cancers, etc.) I don't know the actual statistics, but most people that I know to have quit smoking, did so as a conscious decision due to:

minor health problems (an occasional asthma attack, possibly unrelated to smoking)
Because they felt it prevented them from practicing their favorite sport (shortness of breath or simply low performance)
Because they became parents and didn't want their child inhale smoke
Because their (possibly elderly) relative died from a smoking-related disease.

Thus, another possibility is unrepresentative sample (or another sampling issue/experiment design flaw) - as only extremely healthy smokers and extremely unhealthy nonsmokers were selected.
